# Running Sheet-Specific Macro from Other Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel book that has multiple sheets, subs, and macros. In order to make it a bit more user friendly, I'd like to create a dashboard sheet where the user has to just click buttons to run everything. This is possible easily with the subs, but how can I call a macro from one sheet to another? I can't seem to find any Excel documentation on this.

Answer (score 4):

Put the subs in a Module as opposed to in each sheet object.

To Create a Module right click on the book name in the VBA editor and then choose Insert -> Module.  Any sub will then be accessible to any sheet (or object) within that book.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Sub in a worksheet code module, you can call it from a regular code module (or any other module) like:

```
Sheet1.MySub
```

...where `Sheet1` is the codename of the sheet containing the code you want to run.